# JS - Waiting for promise within function to finish before executing code after function -- possible?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm hoping my title and simplistic code explains what I'm looking to do. I'm trying to call myFunction(), then let those promises resolve with Promise.all... then, and then execute code after myfunction();

```
myfunction() {
  let x = promiseOneFunction();
  let y =  promiseTwoFunction();


 Promise.all([x, y]).then(values => {
            let valOne = = values[0];
            let valTwo = values[1];

            returnObj = {
                fistVal: valOne,
                destination: valTwo
            }

            console.log("return object within promise is ", returnObj);

            return returnObj;
        });

} // end myfunction

myfunction();
console.log("want to have this log after my function is finished");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make `myfunction()` async and `await` it before the `console.log`?

Comment: @NullDev — Making a function `async` is **only** useful if you use `await` **inside** it. If you make that change then it will return a promise that resolves as `undefined` before the `Promise.all` promise resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only (sensible) way to run code when a promise completes is to either:

- Call `then()` on the promise
- `await` the promise

This means you need the promise to be available outside `myfunction`.  Currently that function returns nothing. Change it so it returns the promise returned by `Promise.all([x, y]).then(...)` (which you currently ignore).

```
return Promise.all([x, y]).then(...)
```

Then that promise will be available outside the function:

```
const the_promise = myfunction();
```

And you can call `then` on it.

```
the_promise.then(() => {
    console.log("want to have this log after my function is finished");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that JS is single threaded, all asynchronous functions will be put in to the event queue, which runs after the main thread has finished processing the current function/block of code.

If you want something to happen strictly after the async function you need to put it in a .then() block chained to the async function or you could use the new async/await syntax. It's the same.

With .then()

```
myAsyncFunc().then(result => {
 console.log(result)
})
```

With async/await, you first declare your function as an async function

```
const myAsyncFunc = async () => {
 //Content of your function such as Promise.all
 //Returns a Promise
}
```

Then you call it like:

```
const result = await myAsyncFunc();
console.log(result)
```